# Can't Able to add two FrameLayout Objects in LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android-layout, xamarin.android

while adding two FrameLayout Objects in LinearLayout Object Programmatically, getting the following exception on adding second FrameLayout object to LinearLayout object. Can anyone help.

Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

here is the code

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams param = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 
                               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

MainView = new LinearLayout(_context);
MainView.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

MainView.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
MainView.SetVerticalGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
MainView.SetHorizontalGravity(GravityFlags.Center);




_currentSwipableItemReflectionFrameLayout = _currentSwipableItemFrameLayout;
_currentSwipableItemReflectionFrameLayout.RotationX = 180;
_currentSwipableItemReflectionFrameLayout.Alpha = 0.3f;

MainView.AddView(_currentSwipableItemFrameLayout,param);
MainView.AddView(_currentSwipableItemReflectionFrameLayout,param);

AddView(MainView);
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception says it all. One of the Views you are trying to add using `AddView` already has been added as a child somewhere in the View hierarchy. Hence you must remove it from its parent first before adding it elsewhere.

From the code you have posted it would seem that either or both `_currentSwipableItemFrameLayout` or `_currentSwipableItemReflectionFrameLayout` already has a parent.